# Powershell - replacing codeblock with variable

Tags: variables, powershell, active-directory

I have a simple question regarding code blocks within statements, and variables. My script gathers user input and creates a string that can be used in a powershell statement later on.

```
$filter = @()
While ($filter[-1] -ne "end") {
  $filter += read-host 'Type the name of an OU you want to filter or type "end" to start the script'
  if ($filter[-1] -eq "end") {
    break
  }
  $strFilter += "`$_`.DistinguishedName -notlike `"*" + $filter[-1] + "*`" "
  $strFilter += "-and "
}
$strFilter = $strFilter.SubString(0,$strFilter.length-5)
```

Basically the user will type in however many words, and those words will be appended to the string `"$_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*<WORD>*""` and throw them together with `-and` until the last word entered.

That part works fine, it's using this generated string to gather information that doesn't seem to work; I have a feeling it's something very simple that I'm just missing.

For example:

```
$computers = get-adcomputer -Filter 'ObjectClass -eq "Computer"' -properties "OperatingSystem","CanonicalName","Description"
$filteredComputers = $computers | where-object { $strFilter }
```

$filteredComputers returns the same results as $computers which leads me to believe that the Where-object statement with my string variable isn't doing anything.

Appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Where-Object` scriptblock should evaluate to a Boolean value (or something that can be coerced to a Boolean value). You're providing just a string which, if not empty, PowerShell will coerce to a Boolean $true.  Try something like this instead:

```
$strFilter = @()
while (...) { ...
    $strFilter += "*$($filter[-1])*"
}

$filteredComputers = $computers | 
   Where {$dn=$_.DistinguishedName; @($strFilter | Where {$dn -like $_}).Count -eq 0}
```

This uses a nested pipeline to walk each filter term and apply it to the current object's DistinguishedName - which we had to stash because in the nested pipeline `$_` takes on the value of the current $strFilter array element.  If any of those pass the `like` test then the count will be greater than zero and won't get passed down the pipeline.  Only those that don't match any like (count == 0) should get passed on down the pipeline.

Here's an example of this approach:

```
C:\PS> $strFilter = '*ba*','*bog*'
C:\PS> 'foo','bar','baz','abba','boggle' | 
           Where {$dn=$_; @($strFilter | Where {$dn -like $_}).Count -eq 0}

foo
```

Comment: The `($strFilter | Where {$dn -like $_}).Count -eq 0` seems to be flagging everything as false, for example an input string of "Domain Controllers" will still return false even though it does not belong to any domain controller OU. Shouldn't it be true because there's 0 match? Perhaps I'm misinterpreting something?

Comment: That means it is finding a match against one of the filter terms in `$strFilter`.  What are the contents of `$strFilter`?  Perhaps you have a filter term in there that shouldn't be - maybe a `**`?

Comment: I do not believe `**` is being matched, if you were to press enter during the first while loop that gathers the instances into the array then there would be an occurance of `**`, I would usually check for this before attempting to filter my results. When I copy paste the example above, foo is not returned.

Comment: The last example works on V3 but it doesn't on V2. I updated the examples so they should work on both V2 & V3. Also, can you dump the contents of `$strFilter` right after the while loop?

Comment: so I run the while loop and enter something like `domain controllers` when prompted, and then enter `end` to finish the while loop. Calling $strFilter returns: `*domain controllers*` because of this line you write `$strFilter += "*$($filter[-1])*"`. Hope that helps

Comment: Did you try the updated examples?  I had to tweak it to run correctly on PowerShell V2.

Comment: Success with the V2 tweeks! Could you describe the function of the `@` in V2 and why it isn't required in V3?

Comment: In V2 it is important to make sure the result is an array of strings (even an array of one string) instead of a string.  Count on a string gives the string length and count on an array gives the number of elements in an array.  Putting `@()` around an expression will ensure the result is an array with 0, 1 or N elements in it.

Answer (score 0):

At the point in time when you run this code:

$filteredComputers = $computers | where-object { $strFilter }

What is the value of $strfilter?

If you echo back the value of $strfilter, try manually entering that in it's place, does it work? if so then the words are right, but the execution method is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For example, we need get only the folder Documents or 'My documents' from our user folder:

```
[scriptblock]$filterBlock = { $_.Name -like '*ocum*' }
dir | ?{ & $filterBlock }
```

The answer consists of two parts:
1) cast your string to [ScriptBlock]
2) use the & character to invoke your string (i.e., your scriptblock)